# App crashes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Xcode and I can't seem to make it work... there is no error in the code when I built it but when I press the button linked to the code below the whole app crashes

`step` is currently an `int`.

Does Xcode crash because of this line? `if (*step == 1 || *step == 2){`

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)PressOne{
    if (*step == 1 || *step == 2){
        if ([txtAns.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
            txtAns.text = @"1";
        else if (![txtAns.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
            txtAns.text = [@"1" stringByAppendingString:txtAns.text];
    }
    else {
        txtAns.text = @"1";
        *step = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring step? If you int step;... You can fix the code by removing *step and replacing with step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since step is int, you should reference its value using step, not *step.

Comment: Thks it works :) and here i am thinking the whole night. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *'s before your usage of step, integers are not objective-c objects.

You only need to use pointer notation (*) for when you declare the variables not when you are using them.

The resulting code block might look like this:

```
-(IBAction)PressOne{
    if (step == 1 || step == 2){
        if ([txtAns.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
            txtAns.text = @"1";
        else if (![txtAns.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
            txtAns.text = [@"1" stringByAppendingString:txtAns.text];
    }
    else {
        txtAns.text = @"1";
        step = 1;
    }
}
```